# Some asymptotics with log

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to answer the question whether
$$
(1+\frac{\log x}{x})^x\cdot\frac{\log x}{x}-1\sim \log x-1\text{ as }x\to\infty.
$$

I think this boils down to the question whether
$$
(1+\frac{\log x}{x})^x\sim x\text{ as }x\to\infty.
$$

I think this is equivalent to
$$
x\log(1+\frac{\log x}{x})\sim\log x\text{ as }x\to\infty
$$

and this should be true since $\log x/x\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$, meaning that
$$
\log(1+\frac{\log x}{x})\sim\frac{\log x}{x}\text{ as }x\to\infty, 
$$
hence
$$
x\cdot\log(1+\frac{\log x}{x})\sim x\cdot \frac{\log x}{x}=\log x\text{ as }x\to\infty
$$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$ \left(1+\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^x=e^{x \log \left(1+\frac{\log x}{x}\right) }\sim e^{\log x}=x$$